# Direction of Vectors in Net Force Questions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

While revising mechanics, I stumbled upon the following question:

[image]

[image]

To facilitate comprehension of my question, I would like to present my working as follows:

The net Force must be zero if the skier is moving up with a constant velocity, thus the forces on the axis of the tension force must add up to zero:

F<sub>Tension</sub> - F<sub>f</sub> - mgsinθ = 0

Hence,

F<sub>Tension</sub> = F<sub>f</sub> + mgsinθ

However, when I substitute in my numbers, I get a negative number, because, by convention, I consider left and down as negative and up and right as positive:

F<sub>Tension</sub> = 65 N + 73x(-10)xsin(12º) N = -87 N

I believe this answer to be incorrect because I do not understand the theory correctly. In fact, I believe the equation to be:

F<sub>Tension</sub> = 65 N + 73x(10)xsin(12º) N = 217 N

But how come the negative sign is removed from the acceleration due to gravity, is it because the direction was already stated in a previous equation?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the friction force and the component of the weight are acting down the plane in the same direction. Therefore their signs have to be the same. To put it another way, the negative sign of $g$ is taken into account by assigning a negative value for the force acting down the plane in your first equation, due to the weight of the skier and skis.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Bob is correct, but I'd also add that there is actually an equation that comes before the first equation you wrote (which has all of forces are on one side of the equation). You stated that the forces must "add up" to zero, so the equation would be Ft + Ffr + Fg = 0.

Then, when you substitute negative values for Ffr and Fg (since they're pointed to the left), you'll get the first equation you wrote (with the negative signs). Moving friction and gravity to the other side will simply flip their signs, but they'll still have the same signs as each other.

For these types of problems, I'd find it safer to start off by plugging your numbers in, and then move them around so that your signs don't get confused like here. Good luck!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you!